# Input Javascript array into given HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to append data from a Javascript array to a HTML table.
I have tried appending the data with javascript/jquery, but I am not sure how to iterate through so that each number goes into each grid cell.
I am trying to get the result to look like this (but without the header):

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

```js
var array = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]
];
```

```html
<table id = "table">
<tr>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>

</tr>

<tr>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
 <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>


</tr>
```

Thank you for the help! I am new to learning Javascript and appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
let idx = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     for (var j = i; j < array[i].length; j++){
       elements[idx].innerHTML = array[i][j];
       idx++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this but this works if the table is empty.

```
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table')

  var array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ];

  array.forEach(function (rowData) {   
    var row =  tbl.insertRow();
    rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.append(cell);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really numerous ways of doing this, here is two examples:

1. You have 2 dimensional array, so you loop both dimensions:

   `array.forEach(arr => { // this will loop both dimensions and we will target  tr element`

   `arr.forEach(num => { // this will loop all 3 numbers and we will target td elements`

And you use

`document.querySelector("table tr:nth-of-type(" + tr + ") td:nth-of-type(" + (td++) + ") input")`

to target all inputs directly inside loop.

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

let tr = 1;
let td = 1;
array.forEach(arr => {
  arr.forEach(num => {
    document.querySelector("table tr:nth-of-type(" + tr + ") td:nth-of-type(" + (td++) + ") input").value = num;
  });
  tr++;
  td = 1;
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
  </tr>
```

Or:

2. You use  [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to make one dimension array and for each value just loop inputs +1

Now you have one-liner:

```
array.flat().forEach( arr => document.querySelectorAll('.grid[type="number"]')[num++].value=arr)
```

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

let num = 0

array.flat().forEach( arr => document.querySelectorAll('.grid[type="number"]')[num++].value=arr)
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do in in this way

```js
    let array = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ];
    
    const table = document.querySelector('#table');
    const tableRows = table.rows
    //Convert HTMLCollection to Array and run forEach
    Array.from(tableRows).forEach((row,rowIndex)=>{
        const tableCells = row.cells
        Array.from(tableCells).forEach((cell,cellIndex)=>{
            cell.childNodes[0].value = array[rowIndex][cellIndex]
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use .forEach instead of .length, to prevent errors if the list does not have a length.

```js
var array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
];
const $table = document.querySelector('#table');
array.forEach((a, i) => {
    a.forEach((o, n) => {
        $table.rows[i].cells[n].childNodes[0].value = o;
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
        <td><input class="grid" type="number"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```